# How to use license file according the defined lenguage

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup Studio and I have the term of use in more than one language and I would like the file (defined by the `LicenseFile` variable) corresponding to the language that was defined at the beginning of the installer to be shown in the license window.

Searching, I found some solutions to select files according to the language, changing in the `[Files]` section, but it is not what I need.

Comment: This is covered in the Inno Setup help files. See the `[Languages]` section under `Setup Script Sections`, which demonstrates how to indicate the languages to make available as well as how to use a specific license file for a specified language.

Comment: Also, in the Inno Setup examples folder, you can find `Languages.iss`, which demonstrates how to use language specific files.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve the problem through the link.